# Custom 404 error redirection Asp.net + iis6

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, web-config, iis-6

I need to custom error 404 redirection.
My webconfig is:

```
 <customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/Error404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

I will delete this page `/service/reservation.aspx` and i would like when a client go to this page it will be redirected to `/service/newreservation.aspx` an in other case will be redirected to `/Errors/Error404.aspx`.
I'm using IIS6 and wouldn' like to install any iis extension (because i have about 60 server)

How can do this please?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing now ?

Comment: i need a redirection to the page /service/newreservation.aspx when i access to /service/reservation.aspx and to /Errors/Error404.aspx in others 404 errors cases

Comment: I think , you would need to keep reservatin.aspx and redirect permanently. Check this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1514566.aspx/1) Not sure if there are other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set URL rewrite module and set rules for that. Instead of relying on custom error.

Here is the link how you can install IIS rewrite module in IIS 6.

http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00461/0/Installation-of-URL-Rewriting-module-IIRF-for-IIS6-IIS7.html#iis56

Comment: I have 60 serves, so i prefer to found a code solution o webconfig without installing anything

Comment: Then write a http module and check every request whether it contains url like /service/reservation.aspx and if it that then rewrite the redirect path to it to service/newreservation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deleting the old page, you can set up your own javascript redirect to handle 404's:

Set the Custom Errors in IIS6 to point to an HTML file.

In that file, write a javascript redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var url = document.URL;
  if(url.match("/service/reservation.aspx$"))
  {
      window.location.href = "/service/newreservation.aspx";
  }
  else
  {
      window.location.href = "/Errors/Error404.aspx";

  }
</script>
```